# Ad Hoc Distribution Not Able To Query AWS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ad-hoc-distribution

I have just deployed the app I have created to an Ad Hoc Deployment. I installed the ipa file from itunes onto my iPhone, and now it's not working.

My problem is that none of my `AWSDynamoDB` calls go through. This is strange because if I run the app on my simulator, or install the app from Xcode directly, it works.

Does anyone have information on why this is happening?

Here is an example call:

```
    dynamoDBObjectMapper.load(UserTableRow.self, hashKey: varEmail, 
    rangeKey: nil).continueWithBlock { (task:BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
```

Comment: Would you please explain what is not working? Any stacktrace, error log?

Comment: It turned out to be that when I archived the app for ad hoc distribution the build was set to Release which had the optimization Fastest-Smallest. This apparently skipped over a few crucial lines in my code that waited for AWS to return the query.